# Powershell script causing a strange character in the output

Tags: powershell

I have this script:

```
# Read in the RESOURCE ID values I want to locate
$TextToFind = Get-Content -Path .\ResourceIDs.txt

$Text = ""
$PathArray = @()
$Results = ".\ResultsResourceIDs.txt"

# Now iterate each of these text values
$TextToFind | ForEach-Object {
    $Text = $_
    Write-Host "Checking for: " $Text

    If ((Get-Content .\Resources.rc) | Select-String -Pattern $Text) {
        $PathArray += $Text + "¬Found"
    }
    Else {
        $PathArray += $Text + "¬Not Found"
    }
}



Write-Host "Contents of ArrayPath:"
$PathArray | ForEach-Object {$_}

$PathArray | % {$_} | Out-File $Results
```

It works fine. But the resulting text file has content like:

```
IDR_ANNOUNCE_TEXTÂ¬Not Found
IDC_BUTTON_UNDOÂ¬Found
IDS_STR_CBS2Â¬Not Found
```

Why does it have the strange character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to encoding, you should use `set_content` CmdLet and you can play on `-encoding` param if necessary.

```
$PathArray | % {$_} | Set-Content $Results -Encoding UTF8
```